# Delete old backups from gitlab

Tags: gitlab, backup, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce, gitlab-ee

I have configured *gitlab.rb* file and reconfigured gitlab server `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` to apply configuration changes:

[image]

I generated a gitlab backup with the following command:

```
gitlab-backup create
```

In the firts try, 6 old backups have been deleted. However, I have more backups in *etc/gitlab/config_backup* folder. I have made a second try with the backup creation command and it did not delete any old backup:

[image]

In *etc/gitlab/config_backup* folder lot of old backups still remain:

[image]

BTW, the date configuration of the server is correct:

[image]

What can I do in order to delete all the old backups? Do I need to remove them manually?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your backup name is different- note how your `Creating backup archive: XXXXX` does not match any of your `gitlab_config_XXX.tar` backup names.

I would hazard that you have some other backup task that is backing up your /etc/gitlab folder (which is never backed up by gitlab-backup as you can see in your first screen capture.)

It would also help if you grabbed your `gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/path/here"` and verified your backup location which most likely is not and should not be /etc/gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar issue and had to pass the "--delete-old-backups" parameter/argument to get the old backups to purge.

```
gitlab-ctl backup-etc --delete-old-backups
```

This wasn't required with the main "gitlab-backup create" call, just with the "gitlab-ctl backup-etc" in my case.